# Streaming audio into flash from php

Tags: php, flash, audio-streaming

Hi i was wondering if someone could give me a hand with this... I've managed to gather some information on how to call php from flash to stream the mp3 however im not exactly sure how i go about streaming the data from flash. Below is the code i currently have.

**Flash**

```
function onPlay(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //Load file to play
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("streamAudio.php");
    var urlData:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    urlData.id = id;
    req.data = urlData;

    myMusic.load(req); //myMusic is a Sound object
    myChannel = myMusic.play(); //myChannel is a SoundChannel object

    btn_Play.visible = false;
    btn_Pause.visible = true;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$ID = $_GET["id"];

if ($ID != 0)
{
    //Code to fetch URL from DB

    $url = $row["url"];
    $file = "/" . $url;

    if(file_exists($file))
    {
        header("Content-type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
        header("Expires: -1");
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);

        readfile($file);
    }

    //Close DB
}
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**

Modified the code. The PHP script works if tested directly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're doing what you're doing... you should be able to play the audio very simply:

```
s = new Sound();
s.loadSound("http://someserver/yourscript.php", true);
```

This of course assumes your PHP script is working in the first place.  Note that in many cases, you cannot get the file size of a remote resource prior to downloading it.  Test your PHP script first by hitting it directly.

Comment: Ive updated the code according to your response and have gotten the PHP file to work when accessed directly, however when used with flash it isnt playing the audio. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hmmm, that code works for me.  I'd suggest making a very simple movie with just this code and starting from there.  Also try using Fiddler or Wireshark to make sure Flash is requesting the right resource on your server.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help! Using Fiddler I realized my flash never called the php script, the reason was where i was declaring my Sound object i forgot to set it. :)